# Is it possible to have a remote pooled JMS connection factory (WildFly 10)?

Tags: jms, wildfly

I have a remote java client which looks up a JMS connection factory on Wildfly 10, and everything works fine as expected. It is just a test program; a simple JMS chat system. When I start more than one instance of the chat client sometimes the following message appears:

```
WARN: AMQ212051: Invalid concurrent session usage. Sessions are not supposed to be used by more than one thread concurrently.
```

Followed by a trace.

Now I want to fix this warning, therefore I need a pooled connection factory. But the pooled connection factory isn't available remotely (and as I read it shouldn't be available remotely).

What can I do to fix this warning when I want to start multiple JMS chat clients locally?

I know that the error won't appear when I just different machines.

This is the working non-pooled remote code (but with warning)

```java
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
try {
  context = new InitialContext(properties);
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
  jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext("quickstartUser", "quickstartPwd1!");
} catch (NamingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't caused by not using a pooled connection factory and won't be solved by using a pooled connection factory. The problem is the way your application is using the same JMS session concurrently between multiple threads (as the WARN message indicates). The stack-trace which is logged will show you which class & method is triggering the WARN message.

You need to ensure that your application does not use the same JMS session concurrently between multiple threads. You can do this by giving each thread its own JMS session or by setting up concurrency controls around the session so that only one thread at a time can access it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Can you help me a little bit and show me how to give each thread its own JMS Session?

The above shown code is in the constructor a super class.
And I have a derived class that uses this super class.
When I start two instances of the derived class, I thought (in the beginning) that both instances already use seperate JMS Sessions.
Obviously this is wrong.

Comment: You should post a new question about how to give each thread its own session.